# AWS vuejs Amplify - Failed to pull the backend

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify

I created an app using Admin UI then created a fresh Vue JS application.

When I run `amplify pull --appId d2v01y74i7xjqk --envName staging` on the CLI, I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid feature flag configuration

These feature flags are defined in the "amplify/cli.json" configuration file and are unknown to the currently running Amplify CLI:

graphqltransformer.skipoverridemutationinputtypes
This issue likely happens when the project has been pushed with a newer version of Amplify CLI, try updating to a newer version.
```

I have upgraded amplify to the latest 4.45.0 version.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got this working, and it was frustrating to say the least.

`curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install | zsh && $SHELL`

Once i ran this, it worked for me aftewards.

Comment: Seems the CLI version running with Amplify Admin UI is different from the one in the local machine. I tried to upgrade the local one but it is still not working.  Finally, I got it working again by reinstalling amplify as you did.
I also noticed the version is 5.3.1 before and after I run the upgrade command, while after reinstalling it, the version becomes 8.2.0. I guess something is wrong with the command:  amplify upgrade